# SwiftUI error code, i do not know how to fix it

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
struct QuizView: View {
    // The question pool.
    var questions = [("What is the capital of France?", ["Paris", "London", "New York", "San Francisco"], "Paris"),
                     ("What is the capital of Italy?", ["Rome", "Paris", "Madrid", "Berlin"], "Rome"),
                     ("What is the capital of Spain?", ["Barcelona", "Madrid", "Rome", "Paris"], "Madrid"),
                     ("What is the capital of Germany?", ["Berlin", "Paris", "London", "New York"], "Berlin"),
                     ("What is the capital of the UK?", ["London", "Paris", "Madrid", "New York"], "London"),
    ]

    // The current question.
    @State var currentQuestion = 0

    // The user's score.
    @State var score1 = 0

    // The indices of the remaining questions.
    @State var remainingQuestions = [Int]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            currentView
        }.onAppear {
            questions.shuffle() // shuffle the questions array
            remainingQuestions = Array(0..<questions.count) // recreate remainingQuestions array
        }
    }
}
```

error message:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable

i actually wanted to make the code so that the questions will shuffle but apparently this happened, aslo i'm new to this.

Comment: So what is the error?  Where do you struggle?

Comment: What happened exactly, what error code?

Comment: Hi @Shlok, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please update your code to show a minimal example that reproduces the issue; ideally a `struct ContentView` that someone can paste into Xcode and run. Please take a look at [mcve]

Comment: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable

this is the error

Comment: Where? Which line is causing the error? It's a compile error, not a runtime one.

Comment: questions.shuffle()   creates error , make questions var @State

Comment: Isn’t using @State as mentioned here and done in both the answers for something that only will be changed once a waste of resources and perhaps even misleading? Better to do the shuffling in an init or similar.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a minimal example to aid your situation:

```swift
struct QuizView: View {

    // The question pool.
    @State var questions = [
        ("Q1", "A1"),
        ("Q2", "A2"),
        ("Q3", "A3"),
    ]

    // The current question.
    @State var currentQuestion: (String, String) = ("", "")
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            currentView
        }.onAppear(perform: nextQuestion)
    }

    // Grab the next question, removing it from the question pool.
    func nextQuestion() {
        questions.shuffle()
        currentQuestion = questions.remove(at: 0)
    }
}
```

Since `@State` is used, you can expect `currentView` to update the display of `currentQuestion` when `nextQuestion()` is called.

Comment: This will produce the same error the user reported in the first place. Please see my answer.

Comment: Right. @State is needed to prevent the mutable `self` error. Edited.

Comment: i tried the init function and that shuffles the questions but it only does it when you close the app and restart it.